# How do I parse through a string that is dynamic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I parse through dynamic strings to pull out data?  Example Below: (Written in T-SQL for SQL Server 2008 R2)

The Date to parse through:

```
BUSINESS=12^REFERENCE=9255^ACCOUNT_TYPE=SUPPLIER^SHIPPING_ID=ACHP^
```

I need the `REFERENCE` number when the `ACCOUNT_TYPE=SUPPLIER`.

The Reference Number can be from 1 to 16 characters in length.

My SQL-statement would look something like this:

`SELECT <REFERENCE NUMBER> FROM ACCOUNTS`

The result would look something like this:

```
9255
84
1
151221
415
99
etc...
```

Comment: Is your example data contained in a column in the database? Or is this external data?

Comment: The data is a single column, let's call is KEYS. So the example I gave is the contents of that field.  Subsequent entries are similar however the sizes of the REFERENCE NUMBER vary .  I hope you can assist and thanks for taking  your time to look at it.

Answer (score 4):

You should normalize your data. But here is a solution.

```
declare @accounts table(col1 varchar(max))

insert @accounts values('BUSINESS=12^REFERENCE=9255^ACCOUNT_TYPE=SUPPLIER^SHIPPING_ID=ACHP^')

SELECT replace(data, 'REFERENCE=', '') FROM
(
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') data
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
        REPLACE(col1, '^', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
    FROM @accounts
    WHERE col1 like '%ACCOUNT_TYPE=SUPPLIER%'
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
) x
WHERE data like 'REFERENCE=%'
```

Result:

```
9255
```

Fix your data, that will save you from alot of grief

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number you are looking for from each row containing the example you gave:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(50)

SET @text = 'BUSINESS=12^REFERENCE=9255^ACCOUNT_TYPE=SUPPLIER^SHIPPING_ID=ACHP^'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@text,CHARINDEX('^REFERENCE',@text)+11,
                 (CHARINDEX('^ACCOUNT_TYPE',@text)) 
                 - (CHARINDEX('^REFERENCE',@text)+11))
```

Just replace the `@text` with the field name and your are good to go!